# Godot: Call external method

Tags: godot

Lots of googling and I'm still not grasping what is probably a simple solution.

Scene: "Main". Contains a TileMap "Grid" with a script attached to it "Grid.gd".

Scene: "Player". Contains a KinematicBody2D "Player" with a script attached to it "Player.gd"

In Player.gd, I need to call a method in Grid.gd "_Calculate", pass it two variables, and have it return one variable.

> var vNewPosition = Grid._Calculate(vPlayer, vInputDirection)

Error: The identifier "Grid" isn't declared in the current scope.

Obiously I need to reference the Grid.gd script somewhere to access it, but none of the many examples I have tried work.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: Does the "Main" scene also contains the "Player" scene? If not, how are these scene related?

Comment: They are separate scenes. The Main scene has an instance of the Player scene. Basically there will be multiple Scenes (levels), all of which use an instance of the Player scene.

Answer (score 2):

Given that

> The Main scene has an instance of the Player scene

And

> In Player.gd, I need to call a method in Grid.gd "_Calculate", pass it two variables, and have it return one variable.

I'll give you a few options.

---

### The bad way

If Player knows the node path to Grid, it could use `get_node` to get it.

```
onready var _grid = get_node("../../grid")
```

Or something like that.

And then use it:

```
var vNewPosition = _grid._Calculate(vPlayer, vInputDirection)
```

This approach is, of course, **not recommended**. It will break if the node path is wrong.

---

### The common way

Assuming Player does not know the node path (which is more likely), you can export a `NodePath` variable in Player.gd and use it to get the Grid:

```
exprort var grid_path:NodePath
onready var _grid = get_node(grid_path)
```

Then you need to set the Grid Path property in the Main scene to Grid.

This approach is better than the prior one, in that it does not depend on the path to Grid. However it still depends on a Grid being there. If Player makes no sense when there is no Grid, this approach is OK.

---

### The good way

If Grid may or may not be there, and we want Player to work regardless, we can tweak the above approach:

```
exprort var grid_path:NodePath
onready var _grid = get_node_or_null(grid_path)
```

And remember to check if grid is null before using it:

```
if grid == null:
    return # or whatever

var vNewPosition = grid._Calculate(vPlayer, vInputDirection)
```

Or like this:

```
var vNewPosition = grid._Calculate(vPlayer, vInputDirection) if grid != null else null
```

Which also allows us to specify a default value that `vNewPosition` will take when there is no grid (the `null` at the end of the line). And thus you can have the Player work when there is no Grid, and when there is it will use, and regardless of where (because Main tells it where it is).

*This solution is not completely decoupled, because Player still knows `grid` is a thing that has `_Calculate`. Also we presume there is zero or one, not multiple. I can think of a way to approach that, but decoupling for the sake of decoupling is unnecessary. I'm calling this good enough for your use case. Yet, let me know if you want the over-engineered way.*

Comment: An excellent summary of the available options. Of course, the "real" answer is to use signals and make it so that the player never needs to get a response from the grid (i.e. rather than having the player check whether a grid square is empty before moving, have the player emit a signal saying "I'm trying to move here" and let the grid do the check itself). But, of course, that approach requires something of a paradigm shift and is something I myself am still adjusting to as well. The exported `NodePath` is an excellent compromise that allows folks to program the way they're likely familiar.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Right. By the way, I remind you that emit_signal does not return, nor waits for the connected methods to complete (nor cares if they yield). If the player scripts needs the result, it would require either a signal for the grid to replay, or some other approach that I find hard to justify for this case, yet it is perfectly doable. Edit: I also skipped the more traditional dependency injection by a set_grid function, which really is not idiomatic Godot.

Comment: Thank you both for your time and input. I was, obviously, trying to avoid the grid signalling since I am unfamiliar with that mindset. I will play around with the examples given and contemplate if I need to readjust to this different line of thinking or can do what I want the way I'm used to.  Thanks again!