# Why doesn't this gdscript dialog box code work?

Tags: gdscript

Why doesn't this code work?
I don't know how to describe what happens but here's the code.

```
extends Node2D


onready var dialog_box = get_node("DialogBox")

func _ready():
    ShowDialog("Example")

func ShowDialog(text, font = "DTM-Mono.ttf", time = 0.25):
    var textbox = dialog_box.get_node("Text")
    var dynamic_font = DynamicFont.new()
    dynamic_font.font_data = load("res://Supply (do not delete)/Fonts/" + str(font))
    textbox.add_font_override("font", dynamic_font)
    for character in text:
        textbox.text = textbox.text + character
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(time), "timeout")
```

Comment: Is this something specific of the font? What is `DialogBox` (is it a `WindowDialog`? I don't see you call `popup`)? Given that you don't know how to describe the problem, can you provide a video?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Theroat It's a `Node` that contains the dialog box text and a rectangle on which the text stands just for it looking good. and by `dialog_box` I don't mean a popup just a undertale-like dialog box.

Comment: @Theroat and here's the video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18QrOOw_FZ3MgboVrv59b4sDrFG-AxlmR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: About the video, I was hoping to see it running. However, I notice something on the video you provided. The Label is before the Panel in the scene tree. So the Panel could cover the text. To avoid that, move the Label below the Panel in the scene tree. I don't have the same font file you are using, but I replicated the setup in the video with a different font, and besides the position of the Label, it works fine for me.

Comment: @Theraot Thanks it works now. Also, please post the comment about the layering as an answer so I will be able to mark as the correct answer.

Comment: @Theraot Also, the position is fine for me. Maybe you set the width and height of the text different than me.

Comment: I guessed it would be where the Panel is given that you said it is like an "undertale-like dialog box". Which makes sense, but still a guess. If the guess was wrong, the position of the Label could have been one where the Panel won't cover it. In which case the order of the nodes would have been an aside. - I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working `Control`s what is lower in the scene tree is on top. *You can pretend it is the draw order. Except there is [2D batching](https://godotengine.org/article/gles2-renderer-optimization-2d-batching). But it is as if it were the draw order.*

In this we have a `Label` and a `Panel` siblings on the scene tree, in that order. Like this:

```
DialogBox
├ Text:Label
└ Container:Panel
```

And thus, the `Panel` will appear on top of the `Label`. Meaning the `Label` would behind the `Panel` (assuming they were positioned in the same area. *And they were, because this an attempt to make an RPG-style dialog/text box.*).

---

A simple solution to make the `Label` visible is to reorganize the scene tree, like this:

```
DialogBox
├ Container:Panel
└ Text:Label
```

However, I'm going to suggest a different solution. Reorganize the scene tree like this:

```
DialogBox
└ Container:Panel
  └ Text:Label
```

The reason is that children nodes are positioned relative to their parent. Thus, when you move the `Panel` it also moves the `Label`. *For example, if sometimes the box should appear on the top of the screen and sometimes on the bottom, you only need to move the `Panel`.*

I also want to mention that if you set [`rect_clip_content`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#class-control-property-rect-clip-content) on a `Control`, it will mask children to its rectangle. That is, any part of the children that goes outside the parent rectangle will not be visible. *Which is something you may or may not want.*

---

*And while we are on the topic of moving nodes around. You can export [`NodePath`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_nodepath.html) variables and set them in the inspector panel to reference other nodes ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67665477/402022)).*

*By the way, when working with `Node2D` there is a [`z_index`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html#class-node2d-property-z-index) property. Also, you can use a [`YSort`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_ysort.html) node to deal with fake depth ([example](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/191845/10408)).*

Answer (score 0):

Well, Theraot has made an answer so please see his answer instead, but if you want to see how I explain it, here you go.

First, Theraot asked me

Is this something specific of the font? What is DialogBox (is it a WindowDialog? I don't see you call popup)? Given that you don't know how to describe the problem, can you provide a video?

I responded

@Theroat It's a Node that contains the dialog box text and a rectangle on which the text stands just for it looking good. and by dialog_box I don't mean a popup just a undertale-like dialog box.

and I sent a video like he asked : https://drive.google.com/file/d/18QrOOw_FZ3MgboVrv59b4sDrFG-AxlmR/view?usp=sharing

He responded

About the video, I was hoping to see it running. However, I notice something on the video you provided. The Label is before the Panel in the scene tree. So the Panel could cover the text. To avoid that, move the Label below the Panel in the scene tree. I don't have the same font file you are using, but I replicated the setup in the video with a different font, and besides the position of the Label, it works fine for me.

And well that's the whole thing, See the comments for what happened in more info.